# Set scale of NSView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, scale, nsview

I subclasses NSView to get it scalable. Following Apples '[View Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1)' guide, the bounds should stretch to fit the frame.
When setting the frame size, nothing changes. As I printed the frame size to console, I saw that setFrameSize is doing literally nothing.

So here my question: How can I change set frame size (without setting set bounds size)? (Autolayout disabled)

```
class ScaledView : NSView {
    let scale: CGFloat
    let element: Drawable

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") // not needed, adding it programmatically 
    }

    init(frame frameRect: NSRect, scale: CGFloat, toDraw element: DoubleValue) {
        self.scale = scale
        self.element = element;
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: self.bounds.size.width * scale, height: self.bounds.size.height * scale))
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        element.draw(dirtyRect, parent: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean to set the bounds, not the frame? Altering the frame will change the view's size in its parent's coordinate system, thus changing not just its contents' scale, but also its appearance within its superview. If you just mean to scale the view's contents, the View Geometry guide says:

> To translate or scale the coordinate system, you alter the view's bounds rectangle. Changing the bounds rectangle sets up the basic coordinate system with which all drawing performed by the view begins. Concrete subclasses of NSView typically alter the bounds rectangle immediately as needed in their initWithFrame: methods or upon loading a nib file that contains the view.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like to draw my content on full size and scale it down, so I though of having a smaller frame and bigger bounds. So that's why I though of altering the frame. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Sure--let the frame be what it's going to be (again, that's how the view appears on screen, and is probably controlled by the user or the window or something) but then set your bounds to whatever you wish it to be. You can set the bounds larger than the frame or smaller than the frame to scale your view's contents down or up respectively.